# Can webstorm conveniently create multi-line javascript string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide, webstorm

This is a follow-up question to the question below;

[Convenient way to wrap long SQL statements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647043/convenient-way-to-wrap-long-sql-statements-in-javascript)

Can IDEs like Webstorm conveniently convert a multi-line string into one suitable for javascript and node.js developers?

Convert from

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
         FIRST_NAME  CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         LAST_NAME  CHAR(20),
         AGE INT,  
         SEX CHAR(1),
         INCOME FLOAT )
```

to

```
"CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (" +
             " FIRST_NAME  CHAR(20) NOT NULL," +
             " LAST_NAME  CHAR(20)," +
             " AGE INT," +
             " SEX CHAR(1)," +
             " INCOME FLOAT )";
```

Comment: Don't know for such a key combo, but you can do a multiple carets (many ways to do that - double click Ctrl and hold it the second time, then navigate with keys, or with middle mouse button, or by holding down Alt button and placing carets where you want) and modify all the rows at the same time - Home and End buttons will actually go to first/last character on the row ;)

Comment: Probably you can do it with [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea)

Comment: You could just use an [ES6 template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) and leave it exactly as copy/pasted.